# Applying a content filter to a specific email address in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix

How can I apply a content filter to a *specific* email address in Postfix?

Setting the `content_filter` parameter in `main.cf` applies the content filter to *all* inbound messages.
I only want to apply my filter to a specific address, e.g. support@example.com.

I've defined my filter in `master.cf` using the pipe command as follows:

```
myfilter unix   -       n       n       -       -       pipe
     flags=Rq user=filter argv=/usr/bin/myfilter -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

I'm using Postfix 3.1.4 and I'm not using virtual mailboxes.

Comment: out of the box I am not sure you can do that with postfix. You can use policyd (https://wiki.policyd.org/accesscontrol) but it requires third party software

Answer (score 1):

The classic way of doing per email address processing of mail is to use [procmail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/procmail)

Answer (score 0):

The classic way of doing per email address processing of mail is to use [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/)

Comment: Why duplicate the other answer a week later?